# Trying to use variables to shorten my jquery

Tags: jquery, variables, syntax

I'm trying to shorten the following code(which works) using variables. It seems pretty redundant, so yeah.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.first").click(function()
    {
        if ($('#firsthidden').css('display') == "block")
        {
            $("#firsthidden").hide("blind", "slow");
            $("div.outer").animate({height:200},"slow");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#firsthidden").show("blind", "slow");
            $("div.outer").animate({height:390},"slow");
        }
        if ($('#secondhidden').css('display') == "block")
        {
            $("#secondhidden").hide("blind", "slow");
        }
        if ($('#thirdhidden').css('display') == "block")
        {
            $("#thirdhidden").hide("blind", "slow");
        }
    });
    $("div.second").click(function()
    {
        if ($('#secondhidden').css('display') == "block")
        {
            $("#secondhidden").hide("blind", "slow");
            $("div.outer").animate({height:200},"slow");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#secondhidden").show("blind", "slow");
            $("div.outer").animate({height:390},"slow");
        }
        if ($('#firsthidden').css('display') == "block")
        {
            $("#firsthidden").hide("blind", "slow");
        }
        if ($('#thirdhidden').css('display') == "block")
        {
            $("#thirdhidden").hide("blind", "slow");
        }
    });
    $("div.third").click(function()
    {
        if ($('#thirdhidden').css('display') == "block")
        {
            $("#thirdhidden").hide("blind", "slow");
            $("div.outer").animate({height:200},"slow");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#thirdhidden").show("blind", "slow");
            $("div.outer").animate({height:390},"slow");
        }
        if ($('#secondhidden').css('display') == "block")
        {
            $("#secondhidden").hide("blind", "slow");
        }
        if ($('#firsthidden').css('display') == "block")
        {
            $("#firsthidden").hide("blind", "slow");
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

So I'm trying to shorten this using variables. I've got the code logic down, so I guess it's a syntax/formatting issue. Here's my attempt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = null;
var a = null;
var b = null;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#first").click(function()
    {
        x = $("#firsthidden");
        a = $("#secondhidden");
        b = $("#thirdhidden");
    });
    $("#second").click(function()
    {
        x = $("#secondhidden");
        a = $("#firsthidden");
        b = $("#thirdhidden");
    });
    $("#third").click(function()
    {
        x = $("#thirdhidden");
        a = $("#firsthidden");
        b = $("#secondhidden");
    });
    $("div.clicked").click(function()
    {
        if (x.css('display') == "block")
        {
            $(x.hide("blind", "slow");
            $("div.outer").animate({height:200},"slow");
        }
        else
        {
            x.show("blind", "slow");
            $("div.outer").animate({height:390},"slow");
        }
        if (a.css('display') == "block")
        {
            a.hide("blind", "slow");
        }
        if (b.css('display') == "block")
        {
            b.hide("blind", "slow");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: is this for something similar to a tab content?

Comment: The last time I saw someone using variable names like x, a and b, the developers went as a group to the manager and tried to get the person fired.

Comment: I was going to change them once I got the code working >.>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to reduce all that code down to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var all = $('#firsthidden, #secondhidden, #thirdhidden'),
        arr = ['div.first', 'div.second', 'div.third'];

    all.each(function(i) {
        var this_hidden = this;

        $(arr[i]).click(function() {
            var the_height = $(this_hidden).css('display') == 'block' ? 200 : 390;
            $(this_hidden).toggle("slow", "linear");
            $("div.outer").animate({height: the_height },"slow");
            all.not(this_hidden).hide("slow", "linear");
        });
    });

});
```

- cache the `'#firsthidden,  #secondhidden, #thirdhidden'` elements in `all`
- make an Array of the selectors that get the click handlers `'div.first', 'div.second', 'div.third'`
- use the [`toggle()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method to show or hide the `"#...hidden"` element (`this_hidden`) instead of using an `if` statement
- use the `"#...hidden"` element represented by `this_hidden` to determine the proper height to animate `"div.outer"`
- simply `.hide()` the other two `"#...hidden"` elements without the `if`, excluding the one that is toggled by using the [`not()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method.

---

**EDIT:** Replaced the missing line that animated `"div.outer"`. Thanks to [@natedavisolds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/781573/natedavisolds) for pointing it out.

**EDIT 2:** My selector for the `hidden` elements was wrong. I had `$('#firsthidden', '#secondhidden', '#thirdhidden')` instead of `$('#firsthidden, #secondhidden, #thirdhidden')`.

Also, I copied the reversed `"blind"` and `"slow"` from the question.

Fixed.

**EDIT 3:** I was setting the `the_height` variable too late. Moved it up a line so it runs before the animation begins, and it works.

Shame on me for not testing my code!!!

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/NnyGR/

Comment: +1 very nice.  However, I don't see it addressing the animation for $("div.outer")

Comment: @natedavisolds: Ah yes. I must have deleted that. Updating... Thanks!

Comment: Even better than I expected I'd get it. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Bradley: Ah, I messed up the selector for the `hidden` items, and you had the `"blind"` and `"slow"` reversed, which I copied into my answer. I'll fix it in a second. :o) *(Also, I'm assuming you have `jQueryUI` loaded for the `"blind"` easing.)*

Comment: @patrickdw: Well, it animates div.outer on the second click. Other than that, it doesn't do anything. I _think_ there's a problem with the each method, but I don't really know...

Comment: @Bradley: Ugh, I had the `the_height` variable being set *after* the animation of the `hidden` element began, so it was *always* "block". Just moved it one line up, and finally put together a demo to verify, and it seems to be working. [Here's the demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/NnyGR/)

Comment: @Bradley: Glad I could help! No further gestures of gratitude needed. ;o)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("div.clicked").click(function()
    {
        if (x.css('display') == "block")
        {
            $(x.hide("blind", "slow");
            $("div.outer").animate({height:200},"slow");
        }
```

Needs to be

```
 $("div.clicked").click(function()
    {
        if (x.css('display') == "block")
        {
            x.hide("blind", "slow");
            $("div.outer").animate({height:200},"slow");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#first").click(function()
    {
        MyFunction($("#firsthidden"), $("#secondhidden"), $("#thirdhidden"));
    });
    $("#second").click(function()
    {
        MyFunction($("#secondhidden"), $("#firsthidden"), $("#thirdhidden"));
    });
    $("#third").click(function()
    {
        MyFunction($("#thirdhidden"), $("#secondhidden"), $("#firsthidden"));
    });
    function MyFunction(x, a, b)
    {
        if (x.css('display') == "block")
        {
            $(x.hide("blind", "slow");
            $("div.outer").animate({height:200},"slow");
        }
        else
        {
            x.show("blind", "slow");
            $("div.outer").animate({height:390},"slow");
        }
        if (a.css('display') == "block")
        {
            a.hide("blind", "slow");
        }
        if (b.css('display') == "block")
        {
            b.hide("blind", "slow");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for something like a tabbed content. There are plugins or you can write it on your own. Could be something along the lines of this http://jsfiddle.net/XYGHQ/6/